# Pulling out GET data from URL using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to extract the value of a single $_GET variable contained in a link.

So the html looks like:

```
<div class="news_item"><a href="http://example.com/?p=51">Title</a></div>
```

And I am trying to pull out just '51' from this url using JS:

```
<script>
        function GetURLParameter(sParam, URL) {
            var sURLVariables = URL.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
            {
                var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
                {
                    return sParameterName[1];
                }
            }
         };

        $('.news_item a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var URL = $(this).val('href');
            var sParam = 'p';
            var ID = GetURLParameter(sParam, URL);
            alert(ID);
        });


    </script>
```

When I click on the link I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'split'`  Any ideas what is happening? I can't figure out what I have done wrong..

Comment: How about `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: @Martin It comes back as 'undefined'

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/6W4Rw/

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( $(this).attr("href").split("=")[1] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$(this).attr('href')` will solve your problem however consider something like:

```
 var params = [];
 $(this).attr('href').replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(match, key, value) {
    params[key] = value;
 });

 if (params.Something) {
     // ... it's set.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use PHP?  If so it is as simple as

```
<script>
 var val = "<?php print $_GET['p']; ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of answers telling you to use attr instead of val -- the return value is still undefined because you have not split your string sufficiently to have just the query arguments. You end up checking if "p" === "http://example.com/?p".

Don't forget to split off the non-query portion of the url.